# Git - Branch revert without losing work

Tags: git

For this particular project, I work on two branches "develop" and "master" I have been doing some stuff on "develop" and committed the changes. The client then informed me that they didn't want to go live with the change.

I need to go back, without effecting these changing as I have other changes to make on the repository before this goes live. Is there an elegant way to do this without me losing any work?

I was thinking:

- Branch off "Develop" as it currently is with this feature
- Reset "Develop" so that the previous change is not in
- Once the feature is ready, merge back into develop

EDIT:
I now have three branches:

`master`, `develop` `new`

New contains all of the new features I don't want to make live yet

Develop contains the working copy.

I ran `git reset --hard [NUMBER]`

This has reverted `develop` back to a place before the changes on `new`

I did a few minor changes on `develop` and ran:

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Fix - Contact form"`

`git push origin develop`

But got:

`! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Comment: You don't `revert` anything here. Don't confuse with the `git revert` command. What to did is `reset` your branch

Comment: @nowox I did reset the branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first: you will never loose anything with `Git` unless you really want to *i.e.* removing a branch, removing commits from the `reflog` and executing `git gc`...

If I understand your situation you have this:

```
* 3456789 (master)
| * 2345678 What I dont want yet (develop)
| * 1234567 What I want
* |
|/
*
```

So you want to create a new branch `develop2` reset your branch `develop`to `1234567`, and merge it to `master`:

```
$ git checkout -b develop2 develop
$ git checkout develop
$ git reset --hard 1234567
$ git merge master
```

And you eventually obtain this:

```
* 5678912 (master, develop)
|\ 
* | 
| | * 2345678 What I dont want yet (develop2)
| |/
| * 1234567 What I want
* |
|/
*
```

Comment: Hi, this works and I have reset `develop` back to a previous commit before the major change. However, it still says that I am behind

Comment: What is behind and behind of what?